# Класс Font. Как изменить расстояние между буквами и сделать менее жирным текст?

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Как увеличить расстояние между буквами и сделать еще менее жирным текст?

```
Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
graf.DrawString("Надпись", font, brush, 130, 16);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего, создать свой шрифт, где это все есть и уже его использовать

Comment: Нарезайте и рендерите по по одной букве (получая смещение через  g.MeasureString). Менее жирный - это или какая-то особенность вашей системы, или скриншот, снятый с FontStyle.Bold. У меня на машине ваш код рендерит обычный несверхжирный текст.

Comment: `Courier New` является моноширным шрифтом (все символы одинаковой ширины). К таким шрифтам не применяется кернинг, отсюда и "слипшийся" текст. Либо используйте другой шрифт, либо, как написал выше @PashaPash , рендерите вручную.

Comment: @rdorn Ну он слишком уж жирный и слипшийся,  должен быть намного тоньше, и между буквами должно быть хоть какое-то расстояние. Может быть настройки clear type кривые, или еще что-то системное

Comment: @PashaPash кривые настройки отображения вполне возможно. Или после отрисовки изображение было уменьшено... Ну и да, на картинке "полужирный" стиль, в размере 10 он действительно слипшийся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, объект `Graphics` был получен из класса изображения. Что-то вроде:

```
var img = new Bitmap(...);
graf = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

При этом у него заданы определённые значения свойств, которые приводят к рендерингу текста жирным и на вид слипшимся.

Задайте свойство:

```
graf.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

Попробуйте разные значения.

Answer (score 0):

> Как увеличить расстояние между буквами

Например, используя для рисования текста функции GDI вместо GDI+:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetTextCharacterExtra(
            IntPtr hdc,    
            int nCharExtra 
        );

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool TextOut(IntPtr hdc, int nXStart, int nYStart,
            string lpString, int cbString);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);


        IntPtr hfont;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            hfont = Font.ToHfont();            
        }          

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();

            try
            {
                var res = SetTextCharacterExtra(hdc, 10); //расстояние между символами

                IntPtr prev_font = SelectObject(hdc, hfont);
                string str = "Надпись";
                TextOut(hdc, 130, 16, str, str.Length);
                SelectObject(hdc, prev_font);   
            }
            finally
            {
                e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }      

        }

    }     

}
```